# AspectJ Around Advice

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm writing my master thesis and the title is "Aspect-oriented software development". I have to do a simple project in AspectJ so I set up Eclipse with AspectJ.

I'm having trouble understanding the AROUND advice. I created 3 files:

1) message_out . java

2) message_test . java

3) simple_aspect . aj

In the simple_aspect file:

1) BEFORE and AFTER advice are working as (I think) expected - so, I "commented" them out.

2) The around advice works only for MESSAGE_ONE() method.

My questions are:

1) Can anyone please explain me (from simple_aspect file) the logic behind naming the parameters in the around advice (WHYTHIS, WHYTHAT)??

2) How to make the aspect accept and change TWO arugments (messages) from MESSAGE_TWO() method.

Thanks :)

message_out.java:

```
package mypackage;
public class message_out {
    public static void message_one(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    public static void message_two(String message1, String message2) {
        System.out.println(message1 + ", " + message2);
    }
}
```

message_test.java:

```
package mypackage;
public class message_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        message_out.message_one("AAAAA");
        message_out.message_two("BBBBB", "CCCCCC");
    }
}
```

simple_aspect.aj:

```
package mypackage;
public aspect simple_aspect {
    /*pointcut message_before() : call (* message_out.message_one(..));
    before() : message_before() {
        System.out.println("BEFORE");
    }

    pointcut message_after() : call (* message_out.message_one(..));
    after() : message_after() {
        System.out.println("AFTER");
    }*/

    pointcut message_around(String WHYTHIS) 
    : call(* message_out.message_one(String)) && args (WHYTHIS); 
    void around (String WHYTHAT) : message_around(WHYTHAT) {
        WHYTHAT = "CHANGED";
        proceed (WHYTHAT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain the logic behind why you or someone else chose certain variable names?! In any case, I'd probably go through an AspectJ tutorial-if this is your thesis I'd  start by learning the chosen tool. Describing advice is covered early in ask tutorials and books I've seen since it's pretty essential.

Comment: I am still learning AspectJ and trying to understand Java (I'm new to Java). That's why it a little difficult to understand and "connect" those two tools at once. Where I live is impossible to get the books of this kind, and I'm not a big fan of getting a digital (non legal) copy. Also, the books about AspectJ (that at the end I had to accuire from the net) have some advanced terminology for the begginers (aka newbs) to fully undestand it, and, I don't think that everybody (including me) has the time to read all the materials and fully understand everything, just to write a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found a book: "Mastering AspectJ" from Gradecki J. and Lasiecki N. Took me a few hours to understand the logic behind the around advice. I still don't get it completely, but I got an idea how it should work.

```
pointcut firstPointcut (String s, String t) : call (public void helloWorld(String, String)) && args (s, t);

void around (String s, String t) : firstPointcut (s, t) {
    System.out.println("1st passed value: " + s);
    System.out.println("2nd passed value: " + t);
    s = "changed first one"; 
    t = "changed second one";
    proceed (s, t);
}
```

The below extract helped me understand a "one argument" and thus apply the logic to "two arguments".

Extract from the book:

1) ARGS designator provides the associated advice code with access to the parameters originally passed to the helloWorldUnique() method.

2) The single parameter type in the method signature - only calls with a single parameter should be considered.

3) ARGS designator has a single parameter. This parameter is directly related to the single parameter passed to the method defined as part of our join point.

4) The pointcut completely defines a single parameter based on a combination of the join point and the args designator.

5) Therefore, if the pointcut is expecting a String called s, there should be a join point defined with a String parameter and an args designator with a variable defined as s.

6) When the pointcut uniqueLog is triggered, its String parameter defined by the s variable is made available to the before() advice body.

Comment: Dear Overlord, since you seem to be new to StackOverflow, I recommend you to accept your own answer if it solves your problem in order to close the question. Another option is to delete this question altogether. Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion. I am aware of accepting the answer. The thing is, I must wait 24 hours before accepting my own answer (the script here on stackoverflow told me so)